# nativescript-imagepicker: IOS: Selected image size is different from the original image[Has solution]

Tags: ios, nativescript

**The solution changes will be included in the upcoming release 5.0. Please check the comment from nativescript-imagepicker team:**
https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-imagepicker/issues/217

Thanks for your time.

---

**Selected image size is different from the original image, How to get the original file size ?**

**Which platform(s) does your issue occur on?**

- emulator IOS 11.4 on
  iphone 8 Plus
- real device IOS 11.4 on IPad air

**Please, provide the following version numbers that your issue occurs with:**

- "nativescript-imagepicker": "6.0.4"
- CLI: Nativescript 4.2.0
- "tns-core-modules": "^4.2.1",
- "tns-platform-declarations": "^3.3.0"

**Plugin(s):**
 "devDependencies": {

- "babel-traverse": "6.26.0",
- "babel-types":"6.26.0",
- "babylon":
  "6.18.0",
- "lazy": "1.0.11",
- "nativescript-dev-typescript": "0.7.2",
- "typescript": "~2.7.2"

}

Is there any code involved?
Here I use [@NevinDry's code](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-imagepicker/issues/197#issuecomment-400560349):

the original image is 2 MB, and it became 20MB after 'imageSource.saveToFile(path1, "jpeg");'

```
pickFile() {
        let context = imagepickerModule.create({
            mediaType: 1,//image only
            mode: "single"
        });

        context
            .authorize()
            .then(function () {
                return context.present();
            })
            .then(selection => {
                selection.forEach(selected => {
                    let file;
                    fromAsset(selected).then((imageSource) => {
                        const folder = knownFolders.documents().path;
                        const fileName = "test.jpg";
                        const path1 = path.join(folder, fileName);
                        const saved = imageSource.saveToFile(path1, "jpeg");
                        console.log("saved:" + saved);
                        if (saved) {
                            console.log("Image saved successfully!");
                            file = File.fromPath(path1);
                            console.log("path1:" + path1);
                            this._checkFileSize(path1);
                        }
                    })
                });
            })
            .catch(function (e) {
                console.log(e);
            });
}

 private _checkFileSize(fileUri: string): boolean {
        if (isIOS) {
            var defManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager;
            console.debug("the file path:" + fileUri);
            var fileAttributes = defManager.attributesOfItemAtPathError(fileUri);
            console.debug(defManager);
            var fileSizeNumber = fileAttributes.objectForKey(NSFileSize);
            console.debug(fileSizeNumber);
            var fileSizeNumberB = fileSizeNumber / 1000000.0;
            console.debug("file size in Megabytes");
            console.debug(fileSizeNumberB);

            return true;
        }
    }
```

I also tried below solution: the 2MB image turns to 6MB. Better but not correct.

One more thing maybe related, 'imageSource.saveToFile(filePath, fileType);'
the original file type is jpg , so I keep fileType as jpg here. If uses PNG, the size is bigger.

```
pickfile2(){
 let context = imagepickerModule.create({
            mediaType: 1,//image only
            mode: "single"
        });

        context
            .authorize()
            .then(function () {
                return context.present();
            })
            .then(selection => {
                selection.forEach(selected => {
                    const ios = selected.ios;
                    if (ios && ios.mediaType === PHAssetMediaType.Image) {
                        const opt = PHImageRequestOptions.new();
                        opt.version = PHImageRequestOptionsVersion.Current;
                        PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageDataForAssetOptionsResultHandler(
                            ios, opt, (imageData: NSData, dataUTI: string, orientation: UIImageOrientation, info: NSDictionary<any, any>) => {
                                console.debug(info.objectForKey("PHImageFileURLKey").toString());
                                let srcfilePath = info.objectForKey("PHImageFileURLKey").toString();
                                let fileName = this.extractImageName(srcfilePath);
                                let fileType: "png" | "jpeg" | "jpg" = this.extractImageType(fileName);
                                console.log("fileName:" + fileName);
                                console.log("srcfilePath:" + srcfilePath);
                                //get image instance from data; it doesn't work via 'fromPath'
                                let imageSource: ImageSource = <ImageSource>fromData(imageData);
                                let filePath = path.join(this.filePickerPath, fileName);
                                console.log("filePath:" + filePath);
                                let saved = imageSource.saveToFile(filePath, fileType);
                                console.log("saved:" + saved);
                                if (saved) {
                                    this._checkFileSize(filePath);
                                }
                            });
                    }
                });
            })
            .catch(function (e) {
                console.log(e);
            });
}
```

The playground code is [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=FtrGUW&v=5)

The page went crash once added npm package 'tns-platform-declarations' from it. So please download it if you want to run. Then

1. remove the folder version of nativescript-imagepicker@6.0.4
2. rename package1.json to package.json
3. In references.d.ts, add additiona '/' before '//' to make it as '///' on the two lines.
4. npm install.  That demo should work on your env.

Anyway, Does anyone have idea on it ? Thanks.

Comment: That is because the original image is neither JPEG / PNG. It's a digital native / raw image, you will not have access to original file but just the image data by querying.

Comment: Thanks, @Manoj, That makes sense. Is there any solution to let us making image size as the same as original one?  eg 2 MB rather than 6 MB.